# Converter not found in Spring boot Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to receive info from 2 different tables with a third one in between. Say for example we have a database structure like this
[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOFUU.jpg)

As you can see foo_and_bar table works to create a relation between foo and bar. Now we are able to say that one foo has many bars where bar is a static table with static data ( think of it as a Player -> Items relation and an Inventory table in between). Now in Java the code looks like this:
Foo entity
    @Entity
    public class Foo {

```
@Id
private Long ID;

private String fooData;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
private List<FooAndBar> fooAndBars;
//Getters and setters left out for convenience

}
```

Bar entity
    @Entity
    public class Bar {

```
@Id
private Long ID;

private String BarData;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar")
private List<FooAndBar> fooAndBars;

//Getters and setters left out for convenience
}
```

FooandBar entity 
    public class FooAndBar {

```
@Id
private Long ID;

private String fooData;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
private Foo foo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
private Bar bar;

//Getters and setters left out for convenience
}
```

Now say we want to find all Bars for one Foo. To do that we create a FooAndBarRepository with 1 method findByFooId

```
@RestController
public class FooAndBarRepo extends JpaRepository<FooAndBarRepo, Long>{
     List<Bar> findByFooId(Long id); 
}
```

And write a simple controller to make a GET request like this

```
@Autowired
FooAndBarRepo fooAndBarRepo;

@RequestMapping("/get_bars")
public String getBars(@RequestParam(value = "fooId") Long fooId){
    List<Bars> = fooAndBarRepo.findByFooId(fooId);
    return "success!";
}
```

Now assuming that there is indeed such foo with fooId in our database, if we make the /get_bars?fooId={validIdHere} we will get a ConverterNotFoundExeption like this

```
No converter found capable of converting from type 
[FooAndBar] to type [Bar]
```

The error is thrown at this line of code in our rest controller

```
List<Bar> findByFooId(Long id);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't spring convert FooAndBar to Bar instance?

**EDIT:**
I tried to map a Query by hand to my findByFooId method like this

```
@Query("select bar.id, bar.data from foo" +
       "left join fooandbar fb on foo.id = fb.foo_id" +
       "left join bar.id = fb.bar_id" +
       "where foo_id = :fooId")
List<Bar> findByFooId(@Param("fooId") Long id);
```

The Query works but now I get

```
No converter found capable of converting from type 
[Integer] to type [Bar]
```

So I receive the Data, how do I convert it to an object of type Bar?

Comment: because the repository is of entity `fooandbar`, either map it manually or have two respositories with a reference between them.

Comment: Can you be more specific please. Didn't quite understand what you meant by having two repositories beetwen them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a method returning a `List<Bar>`, it should be in the `BarRepository`. `FooAndBarRepository` is for methods returning `FooAndBar`s.

And if you want a JPQL query to return instances of **Bar**, it should select a Bar, not a `bar.id` and a `bar.data`.

So, use that method in `BarRepository`:

```
@Query("select distinct bar from FooAndBar fb join fb.bar bar where fb.foo.id = :fooId")
List<Bar> findByFooId(@Param("fooId") Long fooId);
```